# How can I remove the numbers in this list?

Tags: python, list

I need to remove the numbers (str) in a list I made for a project, and if is possible I want to save them in a variable. I'm a beginner at python, so I dont know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

```
names = ['MATEO', '3869', 'AGUSTIN', '2641', 'BENJAMIN', '2337', 'TOMAS', '2235', 'LUCAS', '2146', 'SANTIAGO', '2124', 'GASPAR', '1922', 'JOAQUIN', '1750', 'VICENTE', '1717', 'MATIAS', '1712', 'MAXIMILIANO', '1704', 'MARTIN', '1587', 'ALONSO', '1573', 'FACUNDO', '1439', 'LUCIANO', '1402', 'EMILIANO', '1296', 'JOSE', '1287', 'CRISTOBAL', '1267', 'MAXIMO', '1248', 'BRUNO', '1227', 'JULIAN', '1126', 'LIAM', '1088', 'DANTE', '1083', 'GABRIEL', '1082', 'DIEGO', '1052', 'NICOLAS', '1021', 'SANTINO', '950', 'LEON', '946', 'SIMON', '940', 'JUAN', '901', 'SEBASTIAN', '855', 'RENATO', '717', 'IAN', '701', 'THOMAS', '684', 'GAEL', '673', 'AMARO', '670', 'RAFAEL', '656', 'DANIEL', '652', 'PEDRO', '652', 'IGNACIO', '640', 'FELIPE', '638', 'SAMUEL', '578', 'ANGEL', '565', 'BASTIAN', '564', 'FRANCO', '560', 'VALENTIN', '546', 'THIAGO', '530', 'MARIANO', '525', 'LUIS', '502', 'CLEMENTE', '482', 'FRANCISCO', '479', 'DAVID', '464', 'MATTEO', '464', 'JAVIER', '462', 'ISAAC', '444', 'EMILIO', '435', 'PABLO', '434', 'DYLAN', '432', 'DAMIAN', '425', 'CARLOS', '415', 'ALEXANDER', '415', 'NOAH', '411', 'SALVADOR', '409', 'BALTAZAR', '401', 'FERNANDO', '401', 'MATHEO', '381', 'ELIAN', '372', 'AARON', '348', 'LEONARDO', '337', 'GUSTAVO', '335', 'ESTEBAN', '330', 'ELIAS', '328', 'BORJA', '322', 'MANUEL', '307', 'JORGE', '302', 'VALENTINO', '301', 'CRISTIAN', '299', 'ANDRES', '297', 'OLIVER', '296', 'MIGUEL', '277', 'VICTOR', '274', 'ALEJANDRO', '269', 'ETHAN', '238', 'RODRIGO', '238', 'EDUARDO', '231', 'LAUTARO', '231', 'CAMILO', '229', 'JOSUE', '228', 'MATHIAS', '227', 'ALAN', '217', 'FABIAN', '217', 'RAIMUNDO', '216', 'JESÚS', '205', 'EITHAN', '198', 'ALVARO', '194', 'LEANDRO', '183', 'IKER', '177', 'CHRISTOPHER', '174', 'EZEQUIEL', '173', 'ISAIAS', '173', 'MILAN', '173', 'LIAN', '172', 'LUKAS', '170', 'ISMAEL', '169', 'RICARDO', '168', 'CRISTOPHER', '167', 'HECTOR', '162', 'ABRAHAM', '162', 'GUILLERMO', '157', 'LORENZO', '153', 'PASCUAL', '151', 'JEAN', '150', 'AXEL', '148', 'EMMANUEL', '148', 'SERGIO', '148', 'DEMIAN', '147', 'ALFONSO', '142', 'ANTONIO', '140', 'ALEX', '139', 'OSCAR', '138', 'JEREMIAS', '132', 'GONZALO', '128', 'ANTHONY', '127', 'MOISÉS', '126', 'JONATHAN', '125', 'DOMINGO', '124', 'ARTURO', '122', 'NAHUEL', '121', 'MAURICIO', '120', 'MARIO', '119', 'ERICK', '119', 'THEO', '118', 'MARCELO', '116', 'AMARU', '114', 'AUGUSTO', '114', 'PIERO', '114', 'ADRIAN', '114', 'LYAN', '112', 'ABDIEL', '110', 'AUSTIN', '109', 'CÉSAR', '109', 'ROMAN', '109', 'IVAN', '108', 'ENZO', '107', 'KEVIN', '104', 'CLAUDIO', '99', 'EMANUEL', '99', 'MAX', '98', 'CHRISTIAN', '98', 'ALEXIS', '95', 'GASTÓN', '94', 'DEREK', '93', 'FEDERICO', '92', 'MARCO', '91', 'EYDAN', '89', 'ANIBAL', '87', 'PATRICIO', '86', 'RAÚL', '82', 'OCTAVIO', '78', 'JACOB', '78', 'FÉLIX', '78', 'DARÍO', '78', 'LYAM', '77', 'ROBERTO', '75', 'ARIEL', '74', 'ZAID', '72', 'WILLIAM', '72', 'EMIR', '71', 'ISRAEL', '71', 'STEFANO', '71', 'DILAN', '70', 'JAIME', '70', 'BAUTISTA', '70', 'WILLIAMS', '69', 'SANTI', '68', 'EVAN', '68', 'ADRIEL', '68', 'BALTASAR', '66', 'CRISTOFER', '66', 'JHON', '65', 'ELUNEY', '64', 'HUGO', '63', 'CALEB', '63', 'JOSEPH', '63', 'PAOLO', '63', 'KYLIAN', '63', 'SAMIR', '62', 'TAHIEL', '62', 'NEHEMIAS', '62', 'JEREMY', '61', 'JOSIAS', '60', 'LEONEL', '59', 'ANDER', '59', 'IÑAKI', '59', 'OMAR', '59', 'ANGELO', '57', 'ALESSANDRO', '57', 'JOEL', '57', 'BELTRÁN', '56', 'NATHAN', '56', 'JOHN', '56', 'JOSHUA', '56', 'MILOVAN', '55', 'EFRAÍN', '55', 'JORDAN', '55', 'EDWARD', '54', 'HANS', '54', 'GIOVANNI', '53', 'ANTU', '53', 'ARON', '53', 'JARED', '53', 'LOGAN', '52', 'JOHAN', '51', 'MARCOS', '51', 'TOBIAS', '51', 'LEONIDAS', '51', 'EVANS', '50', 'MISAEL', '50', 'JULIO', '49', 'PAULO', '48', 'RODOLFO', '48', 'EDGAR', '48', 'ADOLFO', '46', 'MAURO', '46', 'RUBEN', '46', 'ABEL', '45', 'IZAN', '45', 'ENRIQUE', '44', 'RICHARD', '44', 'ALBERTO', '44', 'NICANOR', '43', 'TEO', '43', 'DANILO', '43', 'ELIEL', '42', 'LUCA', '42', 'EXEQUIEL', '42', 'EIDAN', '42', 'SAID', '41', 'DORIAN', '41', 'LUAN', '41', 'MIKE', '40', 'DERECK', '40', 'INTI', '40', 'SAÚL', '40', 'ALONZO', '39', 'MICHAEL', '39', 'GERARDO', '38', 'LUCCA', '37', 'HERNÁN', '37', 'ANDERSON', '37', 'YAHIR', '37', 'FABIO', '36', 'AMIR', '36', 'ISAI', '35', 'JAYDEN', '35', 'EINAR', '35', 'NELSON', '35', 'ANTUAN', '35', 'GERMÁN', '34', 'LIONEL', '33', 'ANDRE', '33', 'AUKAN', '33', 'BRAYAN', '32', 'BRANDON', '32', 'PATRICK', '32', 'SILVESTRE', '31', 'TADEO', '31', 'ALEN', '31', 'STEVEN', '31', 'PAUL', '30', 'DOMINIC', '30', 'NATANAEL', '30', 'LUKA', '30', 'ADRIANO', '30', 'RAMIRO', '30', 'JAMES', '30', 'MATTHEW', '30', 'DEMIR', '30', 'MARVENS', '29', 'DARIEL', '29', 'ALFREDO', '29', 'GADIEL', '29', 'LUCCIANO', '29', 'ULISES', '28', 'JOAN', '28', 'ELIAM', '28', 'ADAM', '28', 'URIEL', '28', 'YAIR', '28', 'LUCCAS', '28', 'BRYAN', '28', 'CHRIS', '28', 'MARC', '27', 'BERNARDO', '27', 'ROBERT', '27', 'IBRAHIM', '27', 'TEODORO', '26', 'ANDY', '26', 'MASSIMO', '26', 'NEYTHAN', '26', 'OWEN', '26', 'ERIK', '25', 'ELISEO', '25', 'JHOAN', '25', 'CIRO', '25', 'VLADIMIR', '24', 'EYTHAN', '24', 'BAYRON', '24', 'FRANCESCO', '24', 'JOAO', '24', 'YOEL', '24', 'JAIRO', '24', 'ERIC', '23', 'KILIAN', '23', 'OSVALDO', '23', 'JAIR', '23', 'IHAN', '23', 'JUAQUIN', '23', 'FARID', '23', 'MAEL', '23', 'GIANLUCA', '22', 'IÑIGO', '22', 'FERRÁN', '22', 'ARTHUR', '22', 'NEITHAN', '22', 'JACK', '22', 'ANDREW', '22', 'ERNESTO', '22', 'GERALD', '22', 'WOOD', '22', 'ANTOINE', '21', 'FLAVIO', '21', 'EDISON', '21', 'RENÉ', '21', 'BRAULIO', '21', 'PRINCE', '21', 'BORIS', '21', 'NATHANIEL', '20', 'RAPHAEL', '20', 'JUSTIN', '20', 'TRISTÁN', '20', 'GIULIANO', '20', 'VINCENT', '20', 'LUCIO', '20', 'ADONIS', '20', 'LEO', '20', 'ITHAN', '19', 'APOLO', '19', 'VITTORIO', '19', 'NAIM', '19', 'KARIM', '19', 'ADÁN', '19', 'ALEXANDRO', '19', 'ANTHUAN', '18', 'DIDIER', '18', 'NAWEL', '18', 'AQUILES', '18', 'MAICOL', '18', 'FABRIZIO', '18', 'BALTHAZAR', '18', 'SANTY', '17', 'RYAN', '17', 'RAMÓN', '17', 'ELIEZER', '17', 'NÉSTOR', '17', 'FABRICIO', '17', 'DARIEN', '17', 'JONAS', '17', 'ADAMS', '17', 'JERÓNIMO', '17', 'SALOMÓN', '17', 'YAEL', '16', 'ALLAN', '16', 'ALDO', '16', 'KAI', '16', 'LUCIAN', '16', 'EDER', '16', 'IAM', '16', 'OSTIN', '16', 'BENICIO', '16', 'ZABDIEL', '16', 'ELLIOT', '15', 'XAVIER', '15', 'ELEAZAR', '15', 'ESTEFANO', '15', 'EDWIN', '15', 'GERÓNIMO', '15', 'MARCUS', '15', 'HENRY', '15', 'EDUARD', '15', 'EMERSON', '15', 'JUANPABLO', '14', 'GIOVANNY', '14', 'WLADIMIR', '14', 'LEVI', '14', 'WILSON', '14', 'GIAN', '14', 'AIDAN', '14', 'TYRONE', '14', 'JHAIR', '14', 'NEIZAN', '14', 'ITALO', '14', 'WALTER', '14', 'GIANFRANCO', '14', 'GAMALIEL', '14', 'DASTIN', '14', 'JADIEL', '14', 'ESAI', '14', 'ZAMIR', '13', 'JAEL', '13', 'RONALD', '13', 'ZAHID', '13', 'GREGORIO', '13', 'DONATO', '13', 'ROQUE', '13', 'ZAHIR', '13', 'DASTAN', '13', 'RAMSES', '13', 'ROBINSON', '12', 'ANYELO', '12', 'GIORGIO', '12', 'SAM', '12', 'JOSE-TOMAS', '12', 'OSMAN', '12', 'FIDEL', '12', 'BYRON', '12', 'ILIAN', '12', 'ORLANDO', '12', 'CRISTHIÁN', '12', 'MARLON', '12', 'MIRKO', '12', 'RALPH', '12', 'RAYAN', '12', 'STEFAN', '12', 'TYLER', '12', 'GREGORY', '12', 'JUNIOR', '12', 'JEISON', '12', 'VASCO', '12', 'ROOD', '12', 'NIKOLAS', '12', 'FRANCHESCO', '11', 'TIAGO', '11', 'EREN', '11', 'TOMMY', '11', 'BENITO', '11', 'FRANK', '11', 'DOMINICK', '11', 'ELIOT', '11', 'DEYLAN', '11', 'JEFFERSON', '11', 'ÉTIENNE', '11', 'ANTONY', '11', 'MAIKEL', '11', 'JHONNY', '11', 'NEWEN', '11', 'KEYLOR', '11', 'MAYKOL', '11', 'EITAN', '11', 'MAIKOL', '11', 'EIDER', '11', 'JULIANO', '11', 'KILLIAN', '11', 'ABDIAS', '11', 'CRESCENTE', '11', 'SALVATORE', '11', 'HASSAN', '11', 'RENZO', '11', 'VINCENZO', '10', 'BRUCE', '10', 'RAYMUNDO', '10', 'ALÍ', '10', 'YAMIR', '10', 'MILO', '10', 'ARLEY', '10', 'JOE', '10', 'NEFTALÍ', '10', 'ERWIN', '10', 'IANN', '10', 'STEPHANO', '10', 'MARCIAL', '10', 'SANDRO', '10', 'DAVE', '10', 'DAWENS', '10', 'LENIN', '10', 'BRIAN', '10', 'JADEN', '10', 'YEISON', '10', 'EZRA', '10', 'FILIPPO', '10', 'YULIANO', '10', 'YERIK', '10', 'FRANTZ', '10', 'IVAR', '10', 'YADIEL', '10', 'FRANKO', '10', 'WOODLEY', '10', 'JAHAZIEL', '10', 'ELYAN', '10', 'EDEN', '9', 'PASCAL', '9', 'TAYRON', '9', 'AIDEN', '9', 'NATANIEL', '9', 'JACOBO', '9', 'BAIRON', '9', 'DARWIN', '9', 'JIMMY', '9', 'KALETH', '9', 'ASHER', '9', 'BRADLEY', '9', 'ROGER', '9', 'GERARD', '9', 'JOB', '9', 'GUIDO', '9', 'JAZIEL', '9', 'DAWENSKY', '9', 'YEREMI', '9', 'SANTOS', '9', 'ROY', '9', 'CRISTIANO', '9', 'JHOEL', '9', 'DENZEL', '9', 'LION', '9', 'ARMANDO', '9', 'UZIEL', '9', 'KERVENS', '9', 'ILAN', '9', 'NAHUM', '9', 'MAGDIEL', '9', 'BRANCO', '9', 'SANTHIAGO', '9', 'BERNABÉ', '9', 'AWKÁN', '8', 'NEYMAR', '8', 'STEPHAN', '8', 'JAYSON', '8', 'ROLANDO', '8', 'FAUSTINO', '8', 'DÉNIS', '8', 'ALESSIO', '8', 'TAYLER', '8', 'JASON', '8', 'YORDAN', '8', 'NOAM', '8', 'EDINSON', '8', 'HORACIO', '8', 'NIKOLA', '8', 'PIERRE', '8', 'DANNY', '8', 'AYUN', '8', 'REINALDO', '8', 'BASTHIAN', '8', 'ARIAN', '8', 'ENOC', '8', 'YERAY', '8', 'MIQUEAS', '8', 'DEIVID', '8', 'THOMMAS', '8', 'MATTIAS', '8', 'VIGGO', '8', 'FAUSTO', '8', 'CHRIST', '8', 'RAGNAR', '8', 'FABRIZZIO', '8', 'KAEL', '8', 'GIANCARLO', '8', 'NATHANAEL', '8', 'FRANCIS', '8', 'ROMÉO', '8', 'MATTHEO', '7', 'EUGENIO', '7', 'TRAVIS', '7', 'MILLER', '7', 'GHAEL', '7', 'EDRIC', '7', 'SELIM', '7', 'LÁZARO', '7', 'NOEL', '7', 'ETHIÁN', '7', 'LOVENSKY', '7', 'PANGAL', '7', 'CARLO', '7', 'PHILIPPE', '7', 'MICHEL', '7', 'EMIL', '7', 'POLO', '7', 'ALLEN', '7', 'ABDEL', '7', 'CARLENS', '7', 'DENNIS', '7', 'LOUIS', '7', 'GIORDANO', '7', 'ANKATU', '7', 'CAETANO', '7', 'DANTTE', '7', 'REIMUNDO', '7', 'LUCKAS', '7', 'PELAYO', '7', 'KILIAM', '7', 'GIUSEPPE', '7', 'BRUNNO', '7', 'MATIA', '7', 'FABIANO', '7', 'TAYLOR', '7', 'LIFKO', '7', 'FRANKLIN', '7', 'AZIEL', '7', 'ALAIN', '7', 'JIA', '7', 'YULIAN', '7', 'ENMANUEL', '7', 'CARL', '7', 'GIANLUCAS', '7', 'DAYRON', '7', 'MAXIMILIAN', '7', 'GAHEL', '7', 'WENSLEY', '7', 'DARELL', '7', 'GENARO', '7', 'JUN', '6', 'EFRAÍM', '6', 'NIL', '6']
```

I was thinking in a def to use names.pop(x) with x as every number of index that is impair, cause the total of str is 1246, so the index quantity is 1247. But although I have tried many times, I haven't been able to get it right.

Comment: You say you tried many times, please share an attempt that you thought might work, but didn't and people will be able to help you fix or improve it. StackOverflow is here to help you solve problems with your code, but not to write your code for you.

Comment: Is the number every second entry in the list? You could just return a slice with even indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
[item for item in names if item.isnumeric()]
```

It also appears that the list contains a pattern where there's one name followed by one numeric value. If this is the case, you can use list slicing instead:

```py
names[1::2]
```

These output (first three / last three elements):

```py
['3869', '2641', '2337', ..., '6', '6', '6']
```

Answer (score 3):

For instance, you can do something like this:

```py
names = ['MATEO', '3869', 'AGUSTIN', '2641']

numbers = []
for string in names:
    if string.isnumeric():
        numbers.append(string)
```

```py
>>> numbers
>>> ['3869', '2641']
```

Or you can use list comprehensions:

```py
numbers = [string for string in names if string.isnumeric()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and save its output to a variable, like this:

```
names = ['MATEO', '3869', 'AGUSTIN', '2641']
numbers = [item for item in names if item.isnumeric()]

>>> numbers
>>> ['3869', '2641']
```

Comment: Can I ask why someone downvoted my answer? OP wants to save the numbers to a list? this seems like the simplest method (to me) ?